Using rmdir in a FOR loop to delete subdirectories in user/appdata/local/temp
I perform maintenance on several windows 10 VMs. One of the tasks is to clear out the user/temp folders.  I discovered I could use
for /F "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /ad/b') do cmd /c del /s/f/q "%a\AppData\Local\Temp\*.*"

to do this, but it leaves directories and subdirectories behind.  To delete those I discovered I could use
for /D %f in (*) do rmdir %f /s /q

while in the user/temp directory, but I have found no way to automate this to go through all the user directories.  Is this possible?
Not sure what to try.

none of your commands make any sense whatsoever, (to anyone but you,) unless you either explicitly state your current directory, or, better yet, use absolute paths.

Windows has a disk cleanup tool which can be configured to safely remove temporary files. If you want to do it your ill advised way, ... Do PushD "%a\AppData\Local\Temp" && (RD /Q /S . & PopD) 2>NUL.

@MikeNakis
Current directory is c:\users.

@MikeNakis When I run this command from c:\users, it deletes all files in the c:\users<user>\appdata\local\temp directory and all files in its subdirectories for all users in the c:\user directory.

@Compo  I have tried the disk cleanup tool, but it does not delete directories in the temp directory.  Those directories can also contain subdirectories.  Over time or if a user stays logged into a VM, these accumulate to a point to where it severely bogs down the performance of that VM for the user.  I found one user that had almost 90K directories with subdirectories in the temp folder.  Logging into that VM for that user can take at least 15-20 mins.  We do not know why this accumulation happens.  The directories fill up with dsim.exe's and dlls and other files.  All 125-130 VMs do it.

@Compo Thanks that works!  I did have to add a "" at the end of temp.  From "%a\AppData\Local\Temp" to "%a\AppData\Local\Temp".  Without that it was deleting the entire user directory.  No biggie.   I sorta realized that when there was no output and the entry just sorta hung there.  When I aborted it is when I discovered the first few user directories were deleted.  Thanks again!

@USSRAM, my command is correct. This is absolutely incorrect, 'I did have to add a "" at the end of temp. From "%a\AppData\Local\Temp" to "%a\AppData\Local\Temp". Without that it was deleting the entire user directory.'. For some inexplicable reason people seem to think that directory paths end with slashes, that is just rubbish. The backward slash is a path separator, it has no place at the end of a path, because it is not separating anything. I can 100% guarantee that the PushD command entered in a Command Prompt, (cmd.exe), window does not need a terminating directory path separator.

...also if PushD "%a\AppData\Local\Temp" does not work, i.e. the directory as provided does not exist, or cannot be accessed, this command RD /Q /S . and this command PopD will not run, as that is how I designed it! For that reason, unless you decided to not use my exact Do portion of the command, as posted, there is no way that it will delete %a.

There could be used in a batch file:
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir C:\Users /AD-L /B 2^>NUL') do pushd "C:\Users\%%I\AppData\Local\Temp" 2>NUL && (rd /Q /S "C:\Users\%%I\AppData\Local\Temp" 2>NUL & popd)

The command DIR is executed by cmd.exe processing the batch file by running in the background:
%ComSpec% /c dir C:\Users /AD-L /B 2>NUL

The system environment variable ComSpec is defined by Windows default with %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe which expands to C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe.
The command DIR outputs to STDOUT of the background command process

all directory names in C:\Users which are not links like All Users or Default User because of /AD-L (attribute directory and not link)
in bare format which means just the directory names without path because of option /B.

Read the Microsoft documentation about Using command redirection operators for an explanation of 2>NUL. The redirection operator > must be escaped with caret character ^ on FOR command line within ' to be interpreted as literal character when the Windows Command Processor processing the batch file parses this command line before executing command FOR which executes the embedded dir command line with using a separate command process started in background.
The Windows Command Processor processing the batch file captures the output list of directory names without path written to STDOUT of the background command process.
The list of directory names is processed next line by line by FOR on cmd.exe started in background closed itself after finishing the execution of the command dir.
Empty lines are always ignored by FOR which do not exist here. All other lines are by default split up first into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters. If the first space/tab separated string begins with a semicolon after removal of all leading spaces/tabs, the line is ignored completely by default for further processing. That line processing behavior is not wanted here. The directory names can contain one or more spaces and they can even begin with one or more spaces and next a semicolon or begin with just a semicolon. There are specified the FOR /F options eol=| and delims= to redefine the end of line character to a vertical bar instead of a semicolon because of no directory name can contain ever a vertical bar and define an empty list of delimiters to turn off the line splitting behavior and the removal of leading spaces. Each directory name output by dir is assigned therefore as is to the specified loop variable I.
The further processing is explained in full details in my answer on: How to delete files/subfolders in a specific directory at the command prompt in Windows?

The Temp directory of the user directory is made the current working directory for cmd.exe processing the batch file if existing at all. That prevents the deletion of the Temp directory itself. There is nothing else done if the user directory does not have a subdirectory AppData\Local\Temp which is possible as a user can redefine the user environment variables TEMP and TMP and delete next Temp in AppData\Local.
The Temp directory is removed with command RD quietly with all subdirectories. That directory removal fails at least for the directory Temp itself because of being the current working directory of cmd.exe processing the batch file. It can fail also for files being currently opened by other running processes and subdirectories on files being opened by other processes in these directories or other processes use a subdirectory as current working directory. However, the command RD removes as many files and subdirectories as possible including those with hidden or read-only attribute.
The initial current working directory is restored with the command POPD.

The execution of this batch file should be done only after a restart of Windows respectively the virtual machine because of a previously executed installation could result in files existing in %TEMP% or in one of its subdirectories to be moved during a Windows restart to a different directory for the completion of the installation using a pending rename operation for replacing files currently in use during the installation and therefore not possible to replace directly. The deletion of all files and subdirectories in the directory %TEMP% of a user account could result in a corrupted installation on doing it before the necessary Windows restart for the completion of an installation.
To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

dir /?
for /?
popd /?
pushd /?
rd /?

See also single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file for an explanation of the conditional command operator && and the unconditional command operator &.
